# Does clustering also distribute the message queue index in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

Currently are getting tons of new messages and our workers can't handle them as fast as they are coming in. The message queue index gets bigger and bigger untill the set_vm_memory_high_watermark is reached and it stops accepting connections.

So what we could do is increase the memory, but this may not be scalable untill a certain point. Instead I would like to add more servers and distribute the message queue index over several rabbitmqnodes and if we need more memory we just add more servers.

How would I set this up and is this possible or are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Surely increasing the queue capacity is simply postponing the inevitable and you should really be increasing the worker capacity, no?

Comment: @SteveMartin i should have said that for every tasks the worker does it will scheulde 1-20 new tasks. So even if we add more workers it would just keep increasing faster (Untill a certain limit)

But yea your comment makes sense for normal use cases. Thanks! What I think is better is to set the queue to have a max-length.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Distributed RabbitMQ brokers](http://www.rabbitmq.com/distributed.html), chose federation Shovel.

You can store messages on disk if it is an option for you or drop the oldest one (with per-message or per-queue  [ttl](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html)) or set the max [queue length](http://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html).